# GCP Search and Conversation Data Stores and Apps in Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am working with GCP Search and Conversation Data Stores and Apps part of Vertex AI.

I would like to create datastores and apps using Terraform. But I do not see them in the documentation. Are they still not supported by Terraform ? Even in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/create-data-store-es#cloud-storage) I do not see the option of creating them using gcloud.

Comment: If the API cannot support it, then the provider most likely cannot support it either. You would also probably have better luck with support and/or a feature request with Google and Hashicorp.